# get an array from another class in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a list of file names to be used to open images in another class,

```
public String[] getImages(){
  for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
    fileNames[i]= allData[i][10];
  }
  return fileNames;
}
```

then in another class, I have a `FlowPane` which I'm trying to fill with an array of images:

```
String fileNames[] = new string [50];
fileNames = readAllCards.getFileNames();

Image card[] = new Image[50];

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
  card[i] = new Image(fileName[i]);
}
```

I know this code is wrong, but it's what I'm trying to do, I'm just struggling with getting an array from another class and then I think my array of images will work after that.

Comment: how you open the other class? pass the array in the constructor?

Comment: You define getImages() in the first class, then you call getFileNames() in the second. Why? Also, there's no need to allocate the fileNames array in the second class. You just need a reference there because the next line returns the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in the array to `getImages(...)`:

```
public String[] getImages(String[] fileNames){
    //assuming fileNames is initialized 
    for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
        fileNames[i]= allData[i][10];
    }
    return fileNames;
}
```

Now this should work:

```
String fileNames[] = new string [50];
fileNames = readAllCards.getFileNames(fileNames);
```

**NOTE**:  There are many ways to approach this problem.  This is just one simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

A good approach would be to pass in the array as an argument through the constructor. So where you instantiate the class that loads the images, you could do something along these lines:

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(readAllCards.getFileNames());
Image[] cardImages = imageLoader.getImages();
```

Where "imageLoader" is the object that needs access to the array of filenames.

Then in your ImageLoader class, you'd need to add a new constructor:

```
class ImageLoader {

    private String[] filenames;

    public ImageLoader(String[] filenames) {
        this.filenames = filenames;
    }

    public Image[] getImages() {
        Image[] cards = new Image[50];

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            cards[i] = new Image(fileNames[i]);
        }
        return cards;
    }
}
```

If that doesn't help, then I think we'll need more information about your class design. If you can post your classes in their entirety then that would help a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I notice a few issues with your code,

```
public String[] getImages(){
  String[] fileNames = new String[allData.length];
  for(int i=0;i<allData.length;i++){
    fileNames[i]= allData[i]; /* Assuming allData is another String[] */
  }
  return fileNames;
}
```

In your other class,

```
// Just get the fileNames from the call to getFileNames();
String fileNames[] = readAllCards.getFileNames();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would help if you added more info about the context.

In particular, what are the "readAllCards" and "allData" objects?

Comment: readAllCards is the first class (i know, it should start with a capital, my bad), it interprets a file which has all the needed data for cards, like card name, type, and front and back image file names.

allData is a 2d array created from that file.

Comment: This isn't an answer.  This should be a comment.

Comment: I had to add it as an answer as I didn't have the required rep to add a comment!